# Cloud options for file sharing - focusing on multiple "folders/campaigns/programs" on multiple files

Tags: file-sharing

For a small engineering effort. I am looking for a file sharing service that will do the following well:

- share entire folders of files well.
- be easy to allow other non member parties to get their files.
- easy to upload files
- allow 1 paid user. Many good corporate sharing services have a paid X user minimum as the starting level
- handle revisions well

My use cases are the following:

Customer approval and file sharing 
Vendor file sharing

First - Customer side

These are generic 3d files like parasolid, IGES or step. For this the sharing service would be nice if it wrapped a 3d cad viewer in with the service. If a non cad savvy customer downloads a generic cad file having to teach them how to download viewers is painful. Often they work in environments where they can't install software and if they do, their client image resets overnights so what we worked for 15 minutes on today is lost.

It would be nice if the customers could upload files to the same "folder/campaign/program" and that file is clear that it came from a customer.

Super nice would be a resident approval process that keeps a cloud and offsite record.

Vendor side: upload a batch of file (like above) and share the folder rather than 25 or 50 individual file links. Individual file sharing especially SUCKS in this mode.

Both need:
Revisions. Our local file vault does excellent revisions. Unfortunately, by the time that revised file reaches the vendor or customer they have a file with the same name and no revision number. We can save new files to share with a revision number but it would be awesome if the share site could do something - even if it is in the form of a manual tag. Just something clear that this file is in fact version X.

Thoughts? I was originally thinking cloud hoster - the pre set up service providers like Dropbox, etc. I'd be open to hearing about self hosted cloud solutions as well.

Comment: Are you looking for software you can self-host – or for a hosting provider?

Comment: Good question. Cloud.  Needs to be easily accessible in US, Canada and China

Comment: Again: Cloud hoster or cloud software to self-host? Note that the former would be off-topic here, see [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) If you're looking for the latter, please specify what OS your server is running, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions.

Comment: I was originally thinking cloud hoster - the pre set up service providers like Dropbox, etc. I'd be open to hearing about self hosted cloud solutions as well.